# Adding space between geom_pointrange()

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics, geom

I just can't figure out how to add space between two geom_pointrange(s)().

Can anyone give me a hint?
Thanks.

Comment: A little tricky without seeing the structure of your data.frame `df`. Perhaps you could look into combining your `df` and `dfcontrol` into a single dataframe (e.g. using `rbind`) with a third variable like `type` where `df$type <- "exp"` and `dfcontrol$type <- "control"`. Then use `group = type` in your ggplot `aes` with `position_dodge()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position_nudge` does the trick. Using some dummy data:

```
data.frame(expcondition = c('A', 'B'),
           coefs = 6:7) %>%
ggplot(aes(expcondition, coefs)) + 
geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = coefs * .9, ymax = coefs * 1.2)) +
geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = coefs * .8, ymax = coefs * 1.1), col = 'grey',
                ## add some horizontal shift:
                position = position_nudge(x = .1)
                )
```

aside: as user **krfurlong** suggested, merging and [pivoting your data into long format](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) often helps with wrangling your data, not only for `ggplot`ting.

Comment: You are a legend, sir. Thank you so much.